# Number of branching nodes in a tree

Tags: tree, counting

If we know that n is the number of non-branching (less than two children) nodes in a tree, what can be said about the number of branching nodes?

I think that the worst-case scenario is that all non-branching nodes are leaves, in which case the number of branching nodes is equal to the number of internal nodes: n-1 so that the total number of nodes is at most 2n-1. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.

1. Also the minimum number of branching nodes is zero, there is exactly one type of tree with this property (can you describe it?)
2. A tree with the maximum number of branching nodes is a binary tree (why?)

Edit: changed The tree to A tree because there may be several "maximum" trees not all of them binary.

Comment: 1. A linked list? 2. I can't see why, I guess every tree can be binarized to that there are more internal nodes..

Comment: 1 is correct, 2 yes: consider a node with b branches (b > 2). If b is even it can be converted into a node with b/2 branches by adding a branching node for every two branches. If b is odd it can be turned into a node with even branches by moving a branch to one of the leaves without changing the number of non branching nodes.